# Covering pairs with permutations

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations, hamiltonian-path, latin-square

Consider an $n \times n$ matrix $M_n$ with the following properties:

- Each row is a permutation of $A_n \equiv \{1, 2, ..., n\}$.
- Every ordered pair $(i,j)$, $i,j \in A_n$, $i \neq j$, appears as a horizontally adjacent pair in $M_n$ exactly once (which works out since there are $n(n-1)$ such pairs).

Together with user [Sp3000](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12272/sp3000) we've ran some automated search for these matrices. It seems that solutions are not possible for all $n$. Here are some working cases (of course, these are not unique):

$$
M_1 = \left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \end{array}\right) \\
M_2 = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{array}\right) \\
M_4 = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1&2&3&4\\2&4&1&3\\3&1&4&2\\4&3&2&1\end{array}\right)  \\
M_6 = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1&2&3&4&5&6\\2&1&3&6&5&4\\3&1&4&6&2&5\\4&2&6&1&5&3\\5&1&6&4&3&2\\6&3&5&2&4&1\end{array}\right) 
$$

We also have solutions for all further $n$ up to and including $26$. However, we've verified that no solutions exist for $n = 3$ and $n = 5$. So the interesting question is: **for which values $n$ does at least one $M_n$ exist?** Are $3$ and $5$ the only exceptions? When solutions do exist, can one of them be constructed from some obvious pattern or do they always have to be searched for?

A few additional observations on our part:

1. This problem has an equivalent formulation in graph theory. **For the complete digraph $K_n$ can you find a set of $n$ (edge disjoint) Hamiltonian paths whose union covers all edges?**
2. The first and last column of the matrix are necessarily permutations of $A_n$ as well.
3. If we remove the constraint that the individual rows are permutations, then $n = 3$ has solutions, e.g. $(121, 232, 313)$, as does $n = 5$.

Final note: I actually have an application for this problem. I came across this question while trying to devise test cases [for a programming challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/79261/8478) where I wanted to cover all possible cases in as few lists as possible (with $n$ lists of length $n$ being the minimum).

Comment: When $n$ is even, can you decompose the **undirected** complete graph $K_n$ into $n/2$ edge-disjoint Hamiltonian paths?

Comment: @bof is that a genuine question or a hint? I can see that it would imply that there are solutions for all even $n$ on the directed graph, but I'm not sure whether it's true or not.

Comment: As Sp3000 noted in [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29432671#29432671), there are an infinite amount of these for when $n = p - 1$ for some prime $p$. This is because for row $i$ and column $j$, $(i\cdot j \bmod p)$ generates a permutation in every row, and every combination of numbers appears (easy to see if you consider row $i$ an arithmetic progression with step $i$, modulo $p$).

Comment: It was a genuine question, I merely noticed that it works for $N=2,4,6.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A square with the given properties is called a **Tuscan square** (because of the similarity to the more well-known Latin squares. A Tuscan square is also known as a **row-complete Latin square**, and one whose transpose is also Tuscan is a **complete Latin square**).

A Tuscan square for even $n$ can be found by taking an decomposition of the complete undirected graph $K_n$ into $n/2$ Hamilton paths and then reading each path forwards and backwards. A [suitable construction](https://mathoverflow.net/a/60859/46140) dates to the 19th century and is credited to Walecki.

The case of odd $n$ was settled in 1980 by Tillson in [*A Hamiltonian decomposition of $K_{2m}*$, $2m \ge 8$*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0095895680900441), J. Combinatorial Theory, Series B, 29.1. (If the title doesn't seem to match the claim, note that a decomposition of a graph of size $n$ into Hamiltonian *paths* and a decomposition of a graph of size $n+1$ into Hamiltonian *cycles* are equivalent, and the latter is what is meant by a *Hamiltonian decomposition*).

So the short answer is: 3 and 5 are the only exceptions.

There are many constructions, often based around group theory. Ollis, [*Sequenceable Groups and Related Topics*](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/viewFile/DS10/pdf), Electronic J. Combinatorics 20.2 (2013) would be a good starting point if you want to read more broadly than just the Walecki and Tillson constructions.